# How can I get a list of all the Stack Exchange sites where I am currently logged in?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, login

What I am really after is to logout of all the Stack Exchange sites in one go, but I saw a post that it not possible and is on a todo list.

So how can I get a list of the sites that I am currently logged into? Then I can manually go through each one and log out one by one.

PS: logging out of Gmail, closing the browser and opening it again still shows I am logged in to some sites!

Comment: Going through your cookie jar to remove all the Stack Exchange related cookies should work.

Comment: @Mat : tx, now need to know how to do it with Chrome or IE efficiently. But that's a question for different forum, I dont want to clean all my cookies sometimes

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to do that, and it is more of a workaround. Let's hope someone knows a better solution and answers.

Comment: @Mat : but I liked the principal of the idea, nice one.